# django models return empty when use templete but have result witout template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

when i have this in `view.py`

```
def index(request):
    products = product_page.objects.order_by('name')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.name for q in products])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

it return test1,test2

but when change it to

```
def index(request):
    products = product_page.objects.order_by('name')[:5]
    context = {
        'products': products,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

and have a index.html in /dashboard/template/dashboard

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PRODUCTS LISsssT</h1>
    {% if products %}
    test in if
    {{produtcs}}
    <ul>
    {% for product in produtcs %}
    test in for
        <li><a href="#">{{ product.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
         <p>No product are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <ul><li>hello</li></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

i got no `<li>` tag, i using django==2.2.8

Comment: You seem to have a typo,     {% for product in produtcs %} should be {% for product in products %}

Comment: what ? i dont get diffrence

Comment: "produtcs" should be "products"

Comment: oh what a mistake it take 1 our from me ! sry for that. thanks